# Update Nested Array Object passed from Parent to Child in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, object, array, read-only

I have the below array which is being passed from other component.

```
var myArray = [
    {
        "Sequence": 1,
        "Value": 1,
        "sections": [
            {
                "Name": "Section 1",
                "Configurations": [
                    {
                        "Number": 1,
                        "Value": "Fruit"
                    },
                    {
                        "Number": 2,
                        "Value": "Vegetable"
                    }
                ],
                "Cost": {
                    "Currency": "INR"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to loop through this array and add `"isFruit" = true` if `"Value": "Fruit"` and `"isVegetable" = true` if `"Value": "Vegetable"`.

So the **Expected Output** is as below.

```
var myArray = [
    {
        "Sequence": 1,
        "Value": 1,
        "sections": [
            {
                "Name": "Section 1",
                "Configurations": [
                    {
                        "Number": 1,
                        "Value": "Fruit",
                        "isFruit": true
                    },
                    {
                        "Number": 2,
                        "Value": "Vegetable"
                        "isVegetable": true
                    }
                ],
                "Cost": {
                    "Currency": "INR"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Seems the object is ready only and when I try as below it doesn't work. Tried with Spread Syntax but it goes only till 1 level and nested objects are still read only.

Someone please let me know how can I achieve the expected Output array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have no circular or self references in your JSON, you can simply stringify and then parse the array to get a mutable version.

```
let mutableJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonFromParent));
```

I tried a lot of other techniques to avoid this, as it seems pretty clumsy but it works well.

You can also try `Object.assign` but you do need to know if you have array or an object for this one.

```
const newArray = Object.assign([], jsonArrayFromParent);
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped. I was able to achieve the required output.

Comment: Glad to help - this can be tricky esp if you are moving from Aura to LWC

Comment: Yes. That's the activity I am currently working on and was stuck at this part.